# Objective c blocks executing and reusing

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to understand how objective c blocks work.

As far as I understood: block is just a function with no name.

So for example:

```
 ^(int a, int b) { return a + b; };
```

1. How can I invoke it?
2. Can I use it multiple times as I would use a function? If I can then how?
3. To what class will 'self' keyword refer to inside the block?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [*Blocks Programming Topics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1)?  It's chock-full of answers to questions like yours.

Comment: What happened when you tried to answer these questions yourself?

Comment: Does it hurt when you use Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)something
{
    void (^ sample)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"I am %@", self);
    };

    sample();
    sample();
}
```

...or more in keeping with your sample:

```
int (^ adder)(int a, int b) = ^(int a, int b) { return a + b; };
NSLog(@"Result: %d", adder(5, adder(5, 4)));
```